# Children div to expand to the full width size of the parent div with css on the same row

Tags: css, width, parent, children, expand

```
<style>
.classname {
    min-width:248px;
    height:40px;
    max-width:498px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;     
}
</style>

    <div id="maindiv" style="width:3134px;border:1px solid green;height:90px;">
        <div class="classname">
        </div>
        <div class="classname">
        </div>
        <div class="classname">
        </div>
    </div>
```

So no matter how many children the `maindiv` has I whant them to expand to the fullsize of the parent width size.
Ex: If maindiv has 1200px width the children to have 400px each if are 3 or 300px if are 4
ONLY CSS SOLUTION

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little long-winded, but possible

```
/* one item */
.classname:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}

/* two items */
.classname:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.classname:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ .classname {
    width: 50%;
}

/* three items */
.classname:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.classname:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ .classname {
    width: 33.3333%;
}

/* four items */
.classname:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.classname:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ .classname {
    width: 25%;
}

...
```

You will probably also need

```
.classname {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See [Lea Verou's blog post](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/) for more details

Comment: classy, is there a fallback for ie7?

Comment: The IE7 fallback is probably javascript, to count the child elements and update the width on the style.

Comment: This is a neat idea. As long as you don't mind about browsers which don't support the sibling combinator but even then there are JavaScript patches.

Answer (score 0):

`<DIV>`s don't generally run side-by-side; they're block elements. The behaviour you're looking for of multiple elements 'automatically sharing out space' is not an easy one to achieve natively in CSS which is why all the various 'multi-column layout' CSS solutions out there only support a particular set of numbers of columns; for example some of the popular ones support all factors of 12.

The simplest solution to a specific problem like this is to use table cells (or `<DIV>`s with table-cell layout). However, you'd have to set `width=33%` or `width=25%` so you'd have to know how many columns there were. Or use javascript which you indicate you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with only CSS.

If you are generating the `#maindiv` width server-side, you could do some calculating.

example:

```
<?php
    $width = 3134;
    $children = 4;
    $singlewidth = width/children;
?>
<div class="classname" style="width: <?php echo $singlewidth; ?>px;"></div>
```

Or, you could possibly use a `<table>`, depending on what you're trying to do.